# Asp.net web application error The operation has timed out

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, web-services, iis

I have an asp.net web application which connects the asmx web services. Our application access the database records through the web services. On the web application when I access data through the webservice, I am getting an error “The operation has timed out”.  So I have set the “” on the web config of both web services and web application.
I have set the timeout to “-1” on the web application as below

```
EmpWebService _objEmpWebService = new EmpWebService();
_objEmpWebService .Timeout = -1;
return _objEmpWebService.SubmitCon(objem.ToArray());
```

Then I set the time out on the connection string to “60000” as below

```
<add name="conStr" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost\sql2012;database=Assessment;Timeout=60000;user id=sa;password=21*"/>
```

Then I checked the application and still I am getting the same issue. We could not understand why we are getting this error. So we have added error log on the web services to check whether database call started or not. On the error log I could find the request is send to SQL server by web services and no result is received by our web services.

Please find the data access code on the webservices

```
        public SqlConnection DbConnectSql()
    {
        string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ToString();          
        _con = new SqlConnection(str);
        if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _con.Close();
        _con.Open();          
        return _con;
    }


    public void DbCloseSql()
    {           
        if (_con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _con.Close();
        }           

    }       


protected IDataReader Read(List<SqlParameter> sqlParameterList)
    {
        _sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Storedprocedure_select_emp", _dbc.DbConnectSql());
        _sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (sqlParameterList != null && sqlParameterList.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sqlParameterList.Count; i++)
            {
                _sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sqlParameterList[i].ParameterName, sqlParameterList[i].Value);
            }
        }
        return _sqlCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
```

Can any one help me to solve the timeout issue

Comment: You set the timeout for the connection to happen to 60000. But you didn't set the timeout for the command execution. You'll need to adjust that by modifying the command. But you haven't actually shown your data access code, so it's difficult to tell you how to do that. The rest of your question regarding ASMX is completely irrelevant. Focus on the part of your application that's causing a problem, we don't need to know about the rest of it that's working fine. This is part of creating a [MCVE].

Comment: If I increase the value of CommandTimeout, is there any possibility to have performance related issues on my webservices?

Comment: Well it's going to tie up your threads for longer in your web application. I'd look into why the command takes so long in the first place to run. Restructuring your query, adding indexes, restructuring your tables etc might dramatically improve the speed.